# Encoding boolean function in a quantum circuit

Tags: quantum-gate, phase-kickback

Let $U_f$ be the quantum gate such that $| x \rangle  | y \rangle \mapsto | x \rangle |y\oplus f(x) \rangle$, where $x$ is some bit string of size $n$, $|y\rangle$ is a qubit, and is $f$ is some boolean function. It is easy to show that if $| y \rangle = | - \rangle$ then the output is $(-1)^{f(x )} |x \rangle | - \rangle$. That is, the effect of $f(x)$ is moved from the last qubit to the phase of $| x \rangle | - \rangle$.

How can we do the opposite? That is, if we have some quantum gate such that $| x \rangle \mapsto (-1)^{f(x)} | x \rangle$. How can we move the effect of $f(x)$ from the phase of $| x \rangle$ to some other (extra) qubit $| y \oplus f(x) \rangle$?

I've tried entangling $(-1)^{f(x)} |x \rangle$ with $| - \rangle$ but I'm sort of stuck.

Comment: Do you have access to a controlled version of the phase oracle?

Comment: @TristanNemoz: I don't think so

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you have implemented the map that takes $|x\rangle$ to $(-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle$. If you simply have a single qubit gate like that, it will be impossible to get out $|y \oplus f(x)\rangle$ because the $(-1)^{f(x)}$ is a global phase. Instead, let's assume your implementation has a control qubit (which I will draw as the second qubit and label $|y\rangle$. So, it adds the phase *only* if the second bit is inputted to be 1 and if the second bit is 0, it acts like identity. Then, your circuit can be interpreted as $U_f$ but with some Hadamard's around it.

[image]

Now, to get back to a function that puts $|y \oplus f(x)\rangle$ on the second qubit, we may use that the Hadamard is self inverse and obtain the following circuit.

[image]

where the bit within the dotted lines is in your implementation one single gate, which acts on the first qubit and is controlled by the second.

Answer (score 0):

If you control a temporary move/copy of the value register to an ancillary register using Fredkin gates or Toffoli gates, the phasing effect will kickback onto the control qubit.

[image]